# magento - access cart in external PHP file

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Trying to access the magento cart from an external php file, I have loaded Mage and am able to access products & categories but for some reason I'm unable to access the cart information.

Shop is located in www.domain.com/shop/
PHP File is located in www.domain.com/file.php
Magento cookie setting is set to '/'

I have looked at and tried many example of how to get the information and none of them have worked, the code I have at the moment is:

```
<?php
require_once '/home/admin/public_html/shop/appMage.php';                                                        
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart', array('name' => 'frontend'));               
$cartItemsCount = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
$cartTotal = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()); 

echo 'You have '. $cartItemsCount . ' item(s) in your cart. <a class="cartgo" href="'.Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl().'">Checkout</a>';
if($cartTotal > 0){ echo '<span>[&pound;'.$cartTotal.']</span>'; }
echo '</a>';
?>
```

It works perfectly fine within the magento site but not from this external file for some reason. It returns a 0 even though there is a product in the cart.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
// Mage init
require_once '../../app/Mage.php'; 
umask(0);  
Mage::init('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));  

// Get customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 

// Get cart instance
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();

$cartItemsCount = $cart->getItemsCount();
```

see [magento 1.8 add product to cart using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867045/magento-1-8-add-product-to-cart-using-php)

Comment: Unfortunately we are still on 1.7.2 on here so that didnt work!

Comment: I just test the code on v1.7.0 and it does work. What error are you getting? Did you add `echo $cartItemsCount` at the end ?

Comment: Yes - a 0 is what I get for some reason :(  all other integrations are working fine with products/category it's just the cart/session bit.. makes me thing it's something to with the cookie

Comment: Is the domain that this code is been run the same at the magento site domain name?

Comment: Yes exact same domain but the magento install is within a /shop directory and the PHP file is in the domain root

Comment: Try moving the file to /shop and see if that make any different

Comment: That's a good test, and it works perfectly well within the /shop directory

Comment: Take a look at http://www.wikihow.com/Move-Magento-from-Subdirectory-to-Root-Directory-After-Upgrade-with-Cart2Cart cookie path is set to the root folder of your site and that the domain is correct

Comment: Yeah Cookie domain is www.mydomain.com (www. if that makes a difference?) and cookie path is just /

Comment: That should only make a difference on a subdomain level not on a subfolder level ... Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576535/cookie-path-and-its-accessibility-to-subfolder-pages

Comment: What I would recommend is to accept this answer since it work and then ask a new question about setting cookie from a subfolder